# C program that finds the product of two vectors incorrectly outputs zero. Why?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, vector, iteration

I am trying to find the inner product of 2 vectors iteratively, but I seem to be receiving only zero. Thanks for any help. When 1 is imputed as a parameter, and I specify r and c as 1 and 2, and r2 and c2 as 1 and 2, I should be receiving 5. The inner product of 2 vectors is a1 * b1 + a2 * b2 + a3 * b3 ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int inner(int A[], int B[], int n){
  int product = 0;
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    product = product + A[i] * B[i];
  }

  return product;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int *A, *B;
  int r, c, i, j, r2, c2, product;

  printf("Enter values for r and c for vector A: ");
  scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);
  A = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int) * r * c);

  for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
      A[i*c+j] = i + j;

  printf("\nEnter values for r2 and c2 for vector B: ");
  scanf("%d %d", &r2, &c2);
  B = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int) * r2 * c2);

  for(i = 0; i < r2; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < c2; j++)
      A[i*c2+j] = i + j;

  product = inner(A, B, n);

  printf("\nThe inner product of the two vectors is %d\n\n", product);

  return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: Where is B initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule in debugging programs like this is to print key data.  Here, the most key data item is probably the value of `n`.  You've not indicated how you invoke the program, but you read `n` from the argument list (`int n = atoi(argv[1]);`) without checking that you got an argument.  The behaviour you are seeing is consistent with `n == 0`.  So, you can help yourself by writing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int inner(int A[], int B[], int n)
{
    int product = 0;
    int i;

    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("P = %2d, A[%d] = %d, B[%d] = %d\n", product, i, A[i], i, B[i]);
        product = product + A[i] * B[i];
    }

    return product;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s number\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int *A, *B;
    int r1, c1, i, j, r2, c2, product;

    printf("Enter values for r1 and c1 for vector A: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &r1, &c1);
    printf("r1 = %d, c1 = %d\n", r1, c1);
    A = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int) * r1 * c1);

    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c1; j++)
            A[i*c1+j] = i + j;

    printf("\nEnter values for r2 and c2 for vector B: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &r2, &c2);
    printf("r2 = %d, c2 = %d\n", r2, c2);
    B = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int) * r2 * c2);

    for (i = 0; i < r2; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c2; j++)
            B[i*c2+j] = i + j;      // Not A again!

    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    product = inner(A, B, n);

    printf("\nThe inner product of the two vectors is %d\n\n", product);

    return 0;
}
```

Using `bash` (so I don't have to keep on typing numbers when the program prompts me), you can get sample output such as:

```
$ for i in $(seq 6 9); do echo; ./cp $i <<< "3 4 5 5"; done

Enter values for r1 and c1 for vector A: r1 = 3, c1 = 4

Enter values for r2 and c2 for vector B: r2 = 5, c2 = 5
n = 6
n = 6
P =  0, A[0] = 0, B[0] = 0
P =  0, A[1] = 1, B[1] = 1
P =  1, A[2] = 2, B[2] = 2
P =  5, A[3] = 3, B[3] = 3
P = 14, A[4] = 1, B[4] = 4
P = 18, A[5] = 2, B[5] = 1

The inner product of the two vectors is 20


Enter values for r1 and c1 for vector A: r1 = 3, c1 = 4

Enter values for r2 and c2 for vector B: r2 = 5, c2 = 5
n = 7
n = 7
P =  0, A[0] = 0, B[0] = 0
P =  0, A[1] = 1, B[1] = 1
P =  1, A[2] = 2, B[2] = 2
P =  5, A[3] = 3, B[3] = 3
P = 14, A[4] = 1, B[4] = 4
P = 18, A[5] = 2, B[5] = 1
P = 20, A[6] = 3, B[6] = 2

The inner product of the two vectors is 26


Enter values for r1 and c1 for vector A: r1 = 3, c1 = 4

Enter values for r2 and c2 for vector B: r2 = 5, c2 = 5
n = 8
n = 8
P =  0, A[0] = 0, B[0] = 0
P =  0, A[1] = 1, B[1] = 1
P =  1, A[2] = 2, B[2] = 2
P =  5, A[3] = 3, B[3] = 3
P = 14, A[4] = 1, B[4] = 4
P = 18, A[5] = 2, B[5] = 1
P = 20, A[6] = 3, B[6] = 2
P = 26, A[7] = 4, B[7] = 3

The inner product of the two vectors is 38


Enter values for r1 and c1 for vector A: r1 = 3, c1 = 4

Enter values for r2 and c2 for vector B: r2 = 5, c2 = 5
n = 9
n = 9
P =  0, A[0] = 0, B[0] = 0
P =  0, A[1] = 1, B[1] = 1
P =  1, A[2] = 2, B[2] = 2
P =  5, A[3] = 3, B[3] = 3
P = 14, A[4] = 1, B[4] = 4
P = 18, A[5] = 2, B[5] = 1
P = 20, A[6] = 3, B[6] = 2
P = 26, A[7] = 4, B[7] = 3
P = 38, A[8] = 2, B[8] = 4

The inner product of the two vectors is 46

$
```

Echoing inputs and intermediate results is an elementary but powerful technique for debugging programs.

Answer (score 3):

You have a bug where you put values into `A` instead of `B`.

Comment: this was a bug. thanks. however the program still outputs zero.

Comment: @user190494 try debugging: print the values of A[i] and B[i] when you calculate the produce. See if these are the correct values. Print `n`, `r` and `c` to check they are correct. Check your program.

Answer (score 1):

How large are A and B? You allocate n * c * r ints for A, and initialize it as if it were a two-dimensional c*r matrix, so only the first c*r elements are initialized. The remaining (n-1)*c*r elements are uninitialized. Then you calculate the dot product of the first n elements. This doesn't seem to make sense. Do you mean inner(A, B, c*r)?

I suggest that you write a simpler test case for inner().